# Meteor Shell overwriting previous input

Tags: windows, meteor, windows-7

Typing approximately 60 characters causes the cursor to jump back to the start of the same line, overwriting previously input text...

Tested in both ComEmu & default Command Line using Windows 7 64-bit so appears to be a Meteor issue

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with meteor shell. This is caused by your terminal. You can just keep typing and meteor shell will still execute the right command (as you typed it, not as you see it) when you hit enter.

Example:

```js
> var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3m,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 
> x.length
320
```

Comment: Do you know what might be causing it?

Comment: no, I don't know windows terminals very well. But maybe this thread will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24358/how-do-i-get-long-command-lines-to-wrap-to-the-next-line; otherwise, look for a setting regarding number of columns in your terminal program settings..